Auto identify question and zoom in after capturing
I would like to implement a feature on react native.Tthat is to auto-identify and zoom in the question from a captured image. I have provided the a video for your reference.
Expected Result
My current thought is using object detection for this feature. Is my direction correct? Or it involves any other things? Any open source that I can refer to?
